# Linking a library with GHC and Cabal in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, haskell, linker, ghc, cabal

I do have a library that uses the Java Native Interface (which is available as a library libjvm) via the Haskell FFI. Therefor some gluecode is in a c file, the functions are imported via the FFI and that is it.

Using cabal I specify 'frameworks: JavaVM' and magically everything works. However, only Java 6 comes with a framework (since oracle took over there is no such bundle installed with Java 7). So I am trying to link my library with libjvm, not with the framework JavaVM.

I am using the following flags for ghc:

```
  -ljvm
  -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server
  -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib
  -optl-Wl,-rpath,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server
```

They are passed via `--ghc-options` through cabal to ghc. Again the result should be a library. Whether I specify these flags or not, compilation and installation succeeds, but when I build an executable which depends on my library compilation fails (it can not find the symboles from libjvm).

If I link these executables manually (using the exact flags as above) everything is fine. But I do not want to impose that burden on a user of the library, I want the same "comfort" as with the `frameworks: JavaVM` solution.

I am really stuck on this one, how can I get ghc to link my library with libjvm? I have also looked at verbose output ("--ghc-option=-v3") but I can not find any trace of my linking flags (but I can not see any for frameworks either, which is why I really am confused).